# PATCH to Rails app from iOS Client Returning Status 422

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, http, afnetworking, http-status-codes

I have a Rails app with a `Business` model object with a count of `visits`. I have an iOS client that interacts with this Rails app using AFNetworking 2.0, and when a user taps a business in the app, it sends a PATCH to the Rails app, incrementing `visits` for that business. However, I'm getting a status code 422 "Unprocessable Entity" error back from the server, and the business's `visits` count on the server is not getting incremented.

#### AFHTTPSessionManager - iOS

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)visitVenue:(NOTVenue *)venue withCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionBlock {
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self PATCH:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"businesses/%li.json", (long)[venue.identifier integerValue]]
                                  parameters:@{@"visits": @(venue.numberOfVisits + 1)}
                                     success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                                         NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
                                         
                                         if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                 completionBlock(YES);
                                             });
                                         } else {
                                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                 completionBlock(NO);
                                             });
                                         }
                                     }
                                     failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                             completionBlock(NO);
                                         });
                                     }];

return dataTask;
```

}

#### Businesses Controller - Rails

```
# PATCH/PUT /businesses/1
# PATCH/PUT /businesses/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @business.update(business_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @business, notice: 'Business was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @business.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution for this was found on the [Rails API site](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html). Here is the code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?

  protected

  def json_request?
    request.format.json?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the web API allows to *increment* a model objects's counter, it should have a dedicated "method" for that.

Generally, an *Increment Counter* feature won't work reliable if the client itself increments the counter performed on a *local copy* which it received before from the server and then tries to update the server's value via composing a PATCH request where the client sends just the value `local_counter+1`. In the meantime, other clients could have the same idea, in which case the counter value on the server would be become corrupt. Also, one could update the counter on the server to *any* value - which is certainly not desired.

This has the consequence, that the counter variable MUST be *read only* for the clients.

There must be other means (defined by the web API) where a client can accomplish this. For example, a REST API would define a particular "resource" (e.g. some sort of "ticket" or "reservation") which a client can *create*. The *creation* of this resource will have the effect of incrementing the counter variable on the server.

**Edit**

If you are testing a web API, the command line tool `curl` is invaluable:

Test the PATCH request:

In Terminal.app enter this command:

```
curl -sSv -X PATCH \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -d '{"email”:”jappleseed@mail.com"}' \
    http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/123 \
    | python -m json.tool
```

Comment: Thank you, this definitely helps; I'm pretty new to client-server design. While I will definitely change my methodology, could you explain why the PATCH is returning a 422? It still doesn't make sense why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @sethfri I don't know why it sends a 422. If the web service is implemented by you, you should know why ;)   422 (Unprocessable Entity) isn't HTTP 1.1 status code, instead it is defined by WebDAV (RFC 4918). I doubt Rails core will emit that code.

Comment: It's right there in the Rails generated controller code - :unprocessable_entity. I just can't figure out why that's getting sent. My PATCH parameters seem correct, right (if a PATCH were the correct methodology in this case)?

Comment: @sethfri `:unprocessable_entity` maps indeed to status code 422. That is, your `update` method failed, for unknown reasons (for me). You might check the data model.

Comment: CouchDeveloper: 422 *is* an HTTP/1.1 status code; it's just not defined in RFC 2616.

Comment: @JulianReschke Thank's for clarification! As always ;)

Comment: The data model is just Rails generated code. It seems like the only plausible problem is that the request is somehow not being executed correctly.

Comment: @sethfri You should also ensure your POST data is _semantically_ valid JSON which the server understands.

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: @sethfri Since you are using AFN, this is a AFN question. My experience in AFN is limited. IMHO, the "convenient" APIs provided by AFN aren't that appropriate for API requests. I prefer APIs, where I see what header I set, and what is send as data. And, actually, I have some gripes with the way you try to send JSON with AFN.

Comment: @sethfri An invaluable utility to test web APIs is the command line tool `curl`. Go figure:  `$ man curl`.