# Displaying errors on AFNetworking failure

Tags: api, ios7, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, afnetworking-2

Currently using AFNetworking 2.0 from IOS to rails API with Devise.
I can't get the json of errors.

Any idea how to display user.errors in failure block?

```
def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      render :json=> { :token=>user.authentication_token, :email=>user.email }, :status=>201
      return
    else
      warden.custom_failure!
      render :json=> user.errors, status: 422
    end
  end
```

In Xcode:

```
   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
```

Comment: try to remove the status,and you may refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/21303931